# Is there a way to know which index of a list is causing an error when converting from string to dictionary in python?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, try-except

I have a text file with 100000 of dictionaries, each one separated per line, I use the following code to get it inside a list:

```
with open("text.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
```

I had to use encoding='utf8' because otherwise it throws this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 739: character maps to <undefined>

Then I try to convert those strings to dictionaries using the following code:

```
import ast

new_list=[]
for i in file:
    new_list.append(ast.literal_eval(i))

new_list
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-16-a1e01da1b81e>", line 5, in <module>
    new_list.append(ast.literal_eval(i))

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    ,
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried using map() as shown below:

```
r = map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x), file)

new_list=[]
for i in r:
    new_list.append(i)
```

and gives me the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-31-bff21b7ef68b>", line 2, in <module>
    for i in r:

  File "<ipython-input-30-4a53dfb8efc4>", line 1, in <lambda>
    r = map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x), scrap)

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 46, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    ,
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

however when converting the map to a list with:

```
t = list(r)
```

the length of it is 42896 and should be a hundred thousand, and the type of the elements are dict. There is no problem whatsoever when converting string to dictionary as follows:

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,10000):
    a.append(ast.literal_eval(scrap[i]))
```

So I did the same in blocks of ten thousand throughout the entire "file" until one of those blocks give me the next error:

```
f=[]
for i in range(50000,60000):
    f.append(ast.literal_eval(file[i])


     File "<ipython-input-32-c534482a75cc>", line 4
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I want to know which index is throwing the error. I tried so far:
Converting the file to .json:

```
with open("txt.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
    
with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(file, f)
```

and then:

```
with open('file.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


print("Type:", type(data), type(data[0][0]))
Type: <class 'list'> <class 'str'>
```

also this:

```
error_list=[]
counter=0
x=0
another_error=[]
try:
    f=[]
    for i in range(50000,60000):
        f.append(ast.literal_eval(file[i]))
        x=x+1
        another_error.append(x)
        
except:
    counter=counter+1
    error_list.append(counter)
    pass
```

I want the error_list say for example: error_list=[51245, 56235, 57854, ...]
The length of f is now 7080 of 10000 so the error_list must have the indexes of those elements that didn't convert to dictionary.

It's worth to mention I took the time to take a look the text file using notepad++ between lines 50000 and 60000 and everything looks ok to me, both keys and values in spite of being chinese characters or special characters for example both are between double quotes and curly brackets. And I'm using jupyter notebook.

Comment: Seems it would be simpler to store as json and load with json.loads(). I hardly ever need to use ast.literal_eval.

Comment: I followed [this examples](https://appdividend.com/2019/11/13/how-to-convert-python-list-to-json-example/) and didn't work out as expected